# changing docx, pdf document in order it could be printed as book

Tags: java, ms-office, apache-poi

I'm getting a docx. I need to changed it(e.g. with poi) so that it could be printed as a book. i.e. if I have docx with 6 pages, I want to get docx with 3 pages where we have pages 1 and 6 on page 1 of new docx, 2 and 5 on page 2 of new docx and pages 3-4 on page 3 of new docx.

Can someone provide an example(it would nice if example is written java) of such reshuffle?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of tools out there for manipulating PDFs. I usually reach for [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) or [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/)

Since you mention Java, the [Multivalent](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/index.html) project has free (as in beer, not as in freedom) java tools for manipulating PDFs.

Comment: I worked with pdfbof, do you think the problem can be solved with it?

Comment: I haven't used pdfbox, but it looks like you could reorder pages by using PDFSplit and PDFMerger. But, I don't see anything there for converting 1-up to 2-up. From looking at their site, pdfbox doesn't look as mature as the other tools I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This not sounds to be easy, as you have to define the strategy to "compact" or "reduce" pages. Apache POI HWPF for managing .docx is in early development, so seems to not be an option.

Comment: maybe you'll recomend to deal with other library or even to deal with pdf instead of docx at all?

Comment: PDF are not "editable", so avoid trying to modify them, they are "printable" formats, not "editable" as Word (roughly). I can recommend you to try a different approach, find a virtual printer that cad reduce pages (most of them, like FinePrint) and can reorder pages automatically as you want. FinePrint let you to supress pages and reorder manually, so may be any other can print the pages in a "book" fashion.

Comment: Assuming you can find a tool that can do what you want to a PDF, you can use docx4j to create the PDF.